# How do I use the snippet() function using a FTS5 virtual table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, code-snippets, fts5

In the [SQLite documentation for FTS5](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) it is claimed that 5 parameters must be passed to the snippet function:

> The snippet() function is similar to highlight(), except that
> instead of returning entire column values, it automatically selects
> and extracts a short fragment of document text to process and return.
> The snippet() function must be passed five parameters following the
> table name argument:
>
> 1. An integer indicating the index of the FTS table
>    column to select
>           the returned text from. Columns are numbered from left to right 
>           starting at zero. A negative value indicates that the column should
>           be automatically selected.
> 2. The text to insert before each phrase match within the
>    returned text.
> 3. The text to insert after each phrase match within the
>    returned text.
> 4. The text to add to the start or end of the selected text
>    to indicate
>           that the returned text does not occur at the start or end of its column,
>           respectively.
> 5. The maximum number of tokens in the returned text. This
>    must be greater
>           than zero and equal to or less than 64.

I've tried this and it does not work:

```
snippet(1, '<b>', '</b>', '...', 8)
```

How can I use the snippet() function with a FTS5 virtual table in SQLite?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I failed to understand was that I also need to pass the table name as the first parameter, like this:

```
snippet(versesfts, 1, '<b>', '</b>', '...', 8)
```

Hopefully this will save someone a couple of hours.